# Why ngrx entity selectors trigger actions?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am learning NgRx but i dont understand why entity selectors trigger actions. I have been searching the reason but i havent found anything. 
Perhaps i am missing some basics of NgRx/Entity.

This is my demo code:

**selectors.ts**

```
export const selectHeroState: MemoizedSelector<object, HeroesState> = createFeatureSelector<HeroesState>('heros');
export const selectHeroes: (state: object) => Hero[] =  heroAdapter.getSelectors(selectHeroState).selectAll;
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
 //this.store$.dispatch(new GetAll()); I thought this line of code was nescessary to fetch all data from store... 
 this.heroes$ = this.store$.select(selectHeroes); //but i just need this one as it triggers the Get All action
}
```

I hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selectors don't trigger actions. There must be something else that triggered the action?

For example, in my ngOnInit I have this:

```
this.store.dispatch(new productActions.Load());
```

That is what loads my data. Then I can have this:

```
this.products$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getProducts)) as Observable<Product[]>;
```

Which is the selector to get that data for use in the UI.

Just to confirm, I tried commenting out my `dispatch` as you have above, but it stopped working (it did not return any data).

So my guess is that somewhere else in the application it is already loading your data?

Comment: For a detailed introduction to NgRx, check out this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-ngrx-getting-started/table-of-contents

It is FREE this weekend (Friday through Sunday) via this link: https://learn.pluralsight.com/offers/2018/free-weekend

Comment: You are totally right. I was using the `starWith` RxJs operator in a NgRx/Effect which dispatched the GetAll action to the store. Thanks for the help.